# Qt layout not expanding

Tags: qt, qlayout

I have a Qt Widget which has a frame, containg the rest of the widgets.

I only want one of the widgets to expand on maximazing the window, so I've set a max value for the others.

But it will only expand if I set a grid layout to the frame, which messes up the place of the widgets.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to use layouts. There a few cases where they might not be appriopriate, but that's one widget out of 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use any kind of layout ?
Size policy only works if the parent has a layout set.

You can use a combination of different layouts to obtain the desired look, otherwise you will have to calculate the size of the 'expanding widget' yourself in the resize event method of the parent.

Comment: What do you mean by calculate the size?

Comment: Assuming you can't use layouts, you need to override resizeEvent() in the parent QWidget and set the size of the expanding widget to : size of the parent widget - sum of the size of the non expanding widgets.